# HTMLParser only converts the first line of the file

Tags: html, itext, data-conversion

I am using iText for .NET for converting HTML to PDF.
I'm using HtmlParser to convert an HTML page to PDF, but the problem is that Htmlparser only seems to convert the first line to pdf
all other lines from the HTML file are not converted to PDF.

Here is the code

```
Document document = new Document();
        final = new Document();

        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("fck.txt");
        writer.WriteLine(FCKeditor1.Value);
        writer.Close();
        // Changing the extension of txt file to html file
        File.Move("C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\\Common7\\IDE\\fck.txt", "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\\Common7\\IDE\\fck.html");
        PdfWriter writer1 = PdfWriter.GetInstance(final, new FileStream("final1.pdf", FileMode.Create));

        final.Open();
        HtmlParser.Parse(final, "fck.html");
        final.Close();
        File.Delete("C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\\Common7\\IDE\\fck.html");
```

So Please please help me
Any thank u in advance for helping

Answer (score 3):

I use

```
StreamReader tempReader = new StreamReader(tempFile);

        ArrayList p = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(tempReader,st); 

        for (int k = 0; k < p.Count; k++) 
        {
            documento.Add((IElement)p[k]); 
        }

        tempReader.Dispose();
        documento.Close();
```

and works fine too. but i put the dispose at the end

Answer (score 1):

Oh i finally got the solution
Instead of using htmlparser class i have now used htmlworker class
here is the new code

```
ArrayList p = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StreamReader("fck.html"), st);
for (int k = 0; k < p.Count; k++)
{
    final.Add((IElement)p[k]);
}
final.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'System.Collections.ArrayList'

Use it like this:

```
List<IElement> htmlarraylist = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StreamReader(tempFile),new StyleSheet());
                foreach (IElement element in htmlarraylist)
                {
                    document.Add(element);
                }
```