# showing bullets, numbering and images in pdf

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, pdf-generation, itext, string-formatting

In  an asp.net mvc-2 application I need to export a view to pdf. I am using itextsharp to generate pdf. In the application I have documents which contains different instructions with instruction title and different images attached to it. I need to export all the instructions under a document to pdf. The instruction title contains bullets and numbering. It is stored in the database in html format. Also the images attached to each instruction is stored in the db in byte format. My pdf contains a table with each row representing an instruction. I am facing two basic issues in generating pdf with these data :

- When I try to show the title, it is shown with html tags. In the pdf I need to show the title with bullets and numbers(ie. as entered through the editor).
- I need to show byte stream images attached to each instruction in the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

See the first three paragraphs of [my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623963/html-tag-not-accepted-in-itextsharp-and-text-out-of-borders/6626187#6626187) for the answer to your first problem.

For your second question, iTextSharp (and more to the point, the PDF format) supports several formats. For formats not supported you can use the .Net Framework to convert many of them to a usable format. (The easiest to work with is probably JPEG.)

[See this post if you need to know hot to get raw bytes from a database](http://odetocode.com/articles/172.aspx). Once you've got bytes you can use `iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance()` which has (as of 5.1.1) 15 overloads including ones that takes raw bytes, a `System.Drawing.Image` and `System.IO.Stream'.